# MSFlexGridLib Allow User Resize Settings error

Tags: vb.net, reference, compiler-errors, migration, .net-assembly

After converting VB 2008 project to VB 2012, how to fix the error regarding the MSFlexGridLib, The error says:

> Reference required to assembly 'Interop.MSFlexGridLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' containing the type 'MSFlexGridLib.AllowUserResizeSetting'. Add one to your project

The blue line for error occured on the '.AllowUserResizing'

```
.AllowUserResizing = MSFlexGridLib.AllowUserResizeSettings.flexResizeColumns
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your project's properties, select add reference, in COM find Microsoft FlexGrid Control and select it to add it as reference.[image]